Simplicial Approximation
I have simplicial complex $\tau$ which is defined as
$\tau := sd^2\mathbb{S}$ where $\mathbb{S} \subset [0,1]$ such that
$$
\mathbb{S} = \bigl\{ \langle0\rangle, \langle1\rangle, \langle0,1\rangle \bigr\}
$$
so
$$
\tau = \bigl\{ \langle0\rangle, \langle\tfrac{1}{4}\rangle, \langle\tfrac{1}{2}\rangle, \langle\tfrac{3}{4}\rangle, \langle1\rangle, \langle0, \tfrac{1}{4}\rangle, \langle\tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{2}\rangle, \langle\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{3}{4}\rangle, \langle\tfrac{3}{4}, 1\rangle \bigr\}
$$
My function is $g(x) = 2x - x^2$,
and now I want to approximate it by function $h(x) = x$.
I'm having a problem with understanding this situation as the theorem says that if $g(x)\in\tau\implies|h|(x)\in\tau$ then it's a simplicial approximation.
So for example, let's take $g(\tfrac14) = \tfrac{7}{16}.$
We can clearly see that $g(\tfrac14) \in \langle\tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{2}\rangle$.
Also, we have $h\bigl(\tfrac14\bigr) = \tfrac14$.
And here is my concern: we want $g(x)\in\tau \implies |h|(x)\in\tau$, but I'm not clearly sure if $h\bigl(\tfrac14\bigr) \in \langle\tfrac{1}{4}\rangle$
and it's not working or
as $\tfrac{1}{4} \in \bigl[ \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \bigr]$.
I can just write $h\bigl(\tfrac14\bigr) \in \langle\tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{2}\rangle$, and it still holds.
Would appreciate any comments which of these two is right and why.
